# Missing text label at application startup once compiled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The application does a network check at startup. It shows a form during the check that looks like this:

[image]

But when I compile and run the application, the form misses the text label like so.

[image]

Here is the source code of the main file:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Connecting c = new Connecting();//This is the waiting form

        c.Show();

        if (UsefulClass.Ping("www.google.com") == false) {
            c.Close();
            return;
        }

        frmV38 login = new frmV38();

        if (login.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            login.Close();
            Application.Run(new frmMain());
        }
        else {
            Application.Exit();
        }
     }
```

Here is `Connecting.cs`:

```
    public partial class Connecting : Form
    {
        public Connecting()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Connecting_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

How can I show the label in the compiled application?

Comment: Where is _Application.Run(new Connecting());_ ?

Comment: Are you missing InitializeComponent() ? in your Connecting form's constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

after

```
c.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks!It's woring fine but I think it's `DoEvents()` not `DoEvent()`.

Comment: Yah. i write it from my memory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing InitializeComponent() ? in your Connecting form's constructor?

Comment: I writen InitializeComponent() in Connecting.cs